# Beta Function Inequalitys

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

$Beta(1/2,2 + p, 1 + p)=?$

For the values ​​with real parameters p + 2, p + 1, I could not fully solve the beta function. for p>1

Comment: How far did you get? If you show some effort then people are more likely to answer your question

Comment: Could you check your formatting? I don't see any inequalities here.